# How to write this particular Co-related sub-query with ranking function with Joins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Assume you have the following table with City, Hotel, Price. You are required to write code to find cheapest Hotel in each city and % cheaper compared to highest priced Hotel in the same city. Use Joins only. JOINS ONLY!

Here is the sample : please run in TEST_DB only.

```
create table citycheap 
(
     city varchar(100), 
     Hotel varchar(100), 
     prici money
)

insert into citycheap 
values ('Poway', 'Ramada Inn', 100),  ('Poway', 'Elks Oaks', 70),
       ('Poway', 'Days Inn', 85),
       ('Long Beach', 'Days Inn', 95), ('Long Beach', 'Motel 8', 65),
       ('Long Beach', 'Hampton Inn', 105),
       ('San Diego', 'Motel 6', 55), ('San Diego', 'Beach Inn', 115),
       ('San Diego', 'Days Inn', 85)

select * 
from citycheap
```

[image]

Comment: Most people here want expected result as formatted text, not an image (or link to an image.)

Comment: Hey, I am new so just shared a snippet of the expected result! Do comment if you find a solution using JOINS!

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you want a join - if it is not needed?

Comment: I am trying to understand joins better. Ranking functions and derived tables gave me the required result. am looking to see how to perform this with a join as I am unable to think of the logic or the working of a join in such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the "joins only" version. I'd much prefer the CTE/windowed aggregates versions myself:

```
declare @citycheap table(city varchar(100), Hotel varchar(100), prici money)
insert into @citycheap  (city,Hotel,prici) values
('Poway', 'Ramada Inn', 100), 
('Poway', 'Elks Oaks', 70),
('Poway', 'Days Inn', 85),
('Long Beach', 'Days Inn', 95),
('Long Beach', 'Motel 8', 65),
('Long Beach', 'Hampton Inn', 105),
('San Diego', 'Motel 6', 55),
('San Diego', 'Beach Inn', 115),
('San Diego', 'Days Inn', 85)

select
    low.city,
    low.Hotel,
    low.prici,
    100 * (high.prici - low.prici) / high.prici as PercentCheaper
from
        @citycheap low
            left join
        @citycheap low_anti
            on
                low.city = low_anti.city and
                low.prici > low_anti.prici
    inner join
        @citycheap high
            left join
        @citycheap high_anti
            on
                high.city = high_anti.city and
                high.prici < high_anti.prici
    on
        high.city = low.city
where
    high_anti.Hotel is null and
    low_anti.Hotel is null
```

You can hopefully see the symmetry in how I've constructed `low` and `high`. The combination of the `left` join and a `where` clause to ensure the join didn't succeed means that each one is the lowest or highest price within their respective cities.

We then join `low` and `high` together simply. Result:

```
city          Hotel       prici    PercentCheaper
------------- ----------- -------- ----------------
Poway         Elks Oaks   70.00    30.00
Long Beach    Motel 8     65.00    38.0952
San Diego     Motel 6     55.00    52.1739
```

Note also how I used a table variable for the sample data rather than your permanent table. That way I could craft this in *any* database and not worry about leaving any residue behind.

Comment: 55/115=47. something thats incorrect i think for san diego

Comment: @nikhilsugandh - you're thinking of a different percentage calculation. Here, we've apparently been asked to compute "what percentage of the higher price do we avoid paying if we pay the lower price". 55/115 would be "what percentage of the higher price *is* the lower price". Which on reflection you should see those two are complements and sum to 100 (hence why my answer has "52.17" which is the complement of your "47.something")

Answer (score 2):

You do not need joins at all:

```
WITH DataSource AS 
(
    select city
          ,Hotel
          ,prici
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY prici ASC) AS rowID
          ,MAX(prici) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS total_price
    from citycheap
)
SELECT city
      ,hotel
      ,prici as LowPrice
      ,CAST((total_price - prici) * 100.0 / total_price AS DECIMAL(9,2)) as [% Cheapter]
FROM DataSource
WHERE rowID = 1;
```

[image]

---

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT city
          ,MIN(prici) as min_price
          ,MAX(prici) as max_price
          ,CAST((MAX(prici) - MIN(prici)) * 100.0 / MAX(prici) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) as [% Cheapter]
    FROM citycheap
    GROUP BY  city
)
SELECT CH.city
      ,CH.Hotel
      ,CH.prici  as LowPrice
      ,DS.[% Cheapter]
FROM citycheap CH
INNER JOIN DataSource DS
    ON CH.prici = DS.[min_price]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         city, Hotel, prici as min_prici,
         rank() over (partition by city order by prici asc) rank, 
         100-((min(prici) over (partition by city) / max(prici) over (partition by city)) * 100) as percentcheaper
     from 
         d061_citycheap) 
where 
    rank = 1;
```

Sample output:

```
   city         Hotel    min_price rank  percentcheaper
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------

       Long Beach       Motel 8     65  1   38.0952380952380952380952380952380952381
       Poway            Elks Oaks   70  1   30
       San Diego        Motel 6     55  1   0
       San diego        Days Inn    85  1   26.08695652173913043478260869565217391304
```

Comment: I'm trying to get better at using Joins!

Comment: Also, Just took a look at your result closely, It is incorrect brother...

Comment: Your %cheaper calculations are wrong. Please check the required Output!

Comment: for poway 70/100 % is 70   fro long beach 65/105% is 61.9 and so on whats wrong??

Comment: @DhruvinShah its corrected now as said by Damien_The_Unbeliever